# Stop a storyboard after starting in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have used a Storyboard for blinking an `Image`. I've defined the storyboard on XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="AnimateFlicker" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                 From="0"
                 To="1"
                 AutoReverse="True"
                 BeginTime="0:0:1"
                 Duration="0:0:0.08" />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                 From="1"
                 To="1"
                 AutoReverse="True"
                 Duration="0:0:0.4" />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                 From="1"
                 To="0"
                 AutoReverse="True"
                 Duration="0:0:0.08" />
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In my code I've used this code to start the storyboard:

```
private void Blink(bool blink)
    {

        Storyboard storyboard = TryFindResource("AnimateFlicker") as Storyboard;
        if (blink)
        {
            if (storyboard != null)
            {
                imgState.BeginStoryboard(storyboard, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace, true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            storyboard.Stop(); //this line wont work and blinking continues.
        }
    }
```

But as I mentioned in my code `storyboard.Stop()` doesn't work and blinking continues. How can I stop blinking after I start it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Storyboard.Begin` and then `Storyboard.Pause` or `Storyboard.Pause` depending on whether you want the animated target property to still be affected:

```
private void Blink(bool blink)
{
    Storyboard storyboard = TryFindResource("AnimateFlicker") as Storyboard;
    if (blink)
    {
        if (storyboard != null)
        {
            storyboard.Begin(imgState, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace, true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        storyboard.Pause(imgState);
    }
}
```